# why i get output from Integer parameter for null?

Tags: java

in JAVA, why i get output from Integer parameter for null ?

```
package com.company;
class father {
    public void sum(Object a) {
        System.out.println("Object");

    }
    public void sum(Integer a) {
        System.out.println("Integer");

    }

}

public class children extends father {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        father f = new children();
        f.sum(2);
        f.sum(new Object());
        f.sum(null);

    }
}
```

I was expecting null will get cast to object and I will get Object as output, but i get Integer as output.

I got output like this....
Integer
Object
Integer